# Button Click Event fired after Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, postback

In the click event, I have one Insert to the database, and a `Response.Redirect` to preview the record.

The strange issue is if I clicked the button 3 times, I will have 3 new records in the database.  Which is strange, because `Response.Redirect` is executed after the first insert.

N.B:

- The button is causing a full postback because I have to upload files to the server
- I tried `Response.Redirect` with false-true option
- I tried `Server.Transfer`

Here's my code:

```
protected void B_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Insert_Account();

Response.Redirect("index.aspx"); }
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide some code before anyone is really going to be able to help you.

Comment: You may have to prevent multiple clicks. Like disabling the button after click. I experienced this before and I still need to why it's allowed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior if the button has been rapidly clicked and the Insert operation is slow.  Basically, you're submitting multiple requests before the redirect has a chance to return to you.

Simplest solution is to block the button on the client side using javascript.  You can show some sort of processing notification.  This is commonly seen with submitting shopping carts and the like.

Comment: well i used session variables like a flag so i can know where it's the first submit anyway thanks for your suggestion